# How to filter Records in a JSON results on java servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets

I am trying to filter records per gender that i received in form of a JSON response.I have a methord from my DAO class that returns a Json Data so  i Would like to parse its contents so that i can filter with Gender type

```
 String results = bedsBean.allBedsInJson();
 System.out.println(results);
```

gives a List of Records Bellow

```
[{"bedNo": "1", "bedType": "Upper", "roomNo": "1", "roomType": "4500.0", "roomType": "Quadriple", "blockId": "MMA001", "hostelName": "MAMANGINA", "gender": "Female", "status": "VACANT", "id": "3"}]
```

I tried this but It couldnt work

```
  FileReader reader = new FileReader(results);
  JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
  JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
  // get a String from the JSON object
  String bedNo = (String) jsonObject.get("bedNo");
  System.out.println("The first name is: " +bedNo);
  //.......................
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(results);
String bedno = jsonObject.getString("bedNo");
String gender = jsonObject.getString("gender");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use GSon: https://github.com/google/gson.
Create a DTO:

```
public class ObjectDTO() {
   private String bedNo;
   private String gender;
}
```

and do:

```
new Gson().fromJson( yourJsonStringHere, ObjectDTO.class );
```